# How do unique locks work compared to normal mutex locks?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I've came across with this sample of code provided by a [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430264578). Btw this book has bad reviews. I regret that I bought it

```
std::mutex m_mutex;
mutable std::unique_lock<std::mutex> m_finishedQueryLock{ m_mutex, std::defer_lock };

bool m_playerQuit{ false };
void SetPlayerQuit()
{
    m_finishedQueryLock.lock();
    m_playerQuit = true;
    m_finishedQueryLock.unlock();
}
```

I'm not satisfied with the book's explanation of how it works and why should I use it. I already have an idea of how mutex locks work and the implementations of it, but I have a difficulty understanding the second line of the code above. And why does it have a mutable keyword in it?

I'm completely new on C++ Programming. So a basic level of explanation would help me a lot.

Comment: If you're a complete beginner, you should start at the beginning, not at chapter 25.

Comment: `mutable` so you can use it even in a const object, `{}` delimits initialization list, `m_mutex` says which mutex to use, `std::defer_lock` is the locking strategy. What exactly does pose a difficulty?

Comment: The `mutable` keyword should be used for a synchronization object. For example a `GetCount` method in a thread-safe vector implementation would need a critical-section. This method has to be const, but locking requires object (the CS or mutex) to be non-const.

Comment: If that is really an example from the book, throw it away.  Reading it will do you more harm than good.  You are better off guessing.  Oh, do the world a favor and glue it shut before you throw it away.  There's no telling who else might innocently be exposed to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That example looks totally stupid.

The second line is declaring a non-static data member, and

- the member is `mutable` (for reasons given below);
- the member is an object of type `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>`, which is a helper type for locking/unlocking an associated mutex object;
- the member is initialized when an instance of the class is created, by calling its constructor and passing `m_mutex` and the special tag `std::defer_lock` as arguments.

But doing that is stupid, and I'm not surprised the book has bad reviews if it has examples like that.

The point of [`unique_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) is to lock the associated mutex, and then to automatically unlock it when it goes out of scope. Creating a `unique_lock` member like this is stupid, because it doesn't go out of scope at the end of the function, so the code has absolutely no advantage over:

```
mutable std::mutex m_mutex;

bool m_playerQuit{ false };

void SetPlayerQuit()
{
    m_mutex.lock();
    m_playerQuit = true;
    m_mutex.unlock();
}
```

But this manual unlocking has all the problems that `unique_lock` was designed to solve, so it should be using a scoped lock (either `unique_lock` or `lock_guard`) but only in the function scope, not as a member:

```
mutable std::mutex m_mutex;

bool m_playerQuit{ false };

void SetPlayerQuit()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    m_playerQuit = true;
}   // m_mutex is automatically unlocked by the ~lock_guard destructor
```

The [`mutable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) keyword is necessary so that you can lock the mutex in `const` member functions. Locking and unlocking a mutex is a non-const operation that modifies the mutex, which would not be allowed in a `const` member if it wasn't mutable.

Answer (score 1):

The `unique_lock` is a [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) system.  When created, taking the `mutex` as parameter, it will lock the mutex and when leaving the scope it is destroyed, thus unlocking the mutex.  When you need to unlock earlier, you can call the `unlock()` function like in your example.

Using the `unique_lock` like in your example doesn't create added value over using the mutex directly.

Answer (score 0):

All answers explain very well why the example is not good. I will answer when you would want to use a `std::unique_lock` instead of a `std::lock_guard`.

When a thread is waiting on something, one may use a `std::condition_variable`. A condition variable makes use of deferred locking and therefore uses a `unique_lock`, which allows deferred locking. I don't think you explicitly need to say you need deferred locking, as in the example.

To grasp these concepts, you first need to learn what RAII is. Then have a look at [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock). An example of the condition variables can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable).

Comment: For the stupid example in the book it does need to defer locking, so that it doesn't get locked in the constructor and is only locked explicitly inside each member function (but that's what makes it so stupid, as a local variable without `defer_lock` has the same effect! :-).  Typical uses of condition variables don't need to defer locking either, the reason `std::condition_variable` uses `std::unique_lock` is that it needs to unlock and re-lock the mutex, and `lock_guard` doesn't provide any way to do that, it stays locked until its destructor.